# How can I dynamicly load js files with require with the correct dependency?

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am attempting to (and failing miserably) to load a js file only if the element is on the screen. In this example, I want to load the contact module only if the contact form is currently on the page. Without a doubt, it's an implementation issue. I can see that `form,js` is getting loaded last...

[image]

The error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: form.renderFeedback is not a function
```

**application.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    ....
    if ($('#contactForm').length) {
        /**
         * Contact form initialization.
         *
         * @param {object} contact | Contact form module.
         * @returns {object}
         *
         */
        require(['modules/forms/contact'], function (contact) {
            contact.initialize();
        });
    }

    return {
        'initialize': initialize
    };
});
```

**contact.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery.validate',
], function ($, form) {

    var initialize = function () {
        ....
        require(['modules/system/form'], function (form) {
            ....
            form.renderFeedback('error', $element, val);
        });
    };

    return {
        'initialize': initialize
    };
});
```

**form.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    var renderFeedback = function (type, $field, message) {
        ....
    };

    return {
        'renderFeedback': renderFeedback
    };
});
```

**EDIT**

To further prove that it's me & my lack of *true* understanding of require best practices, I have updated my current codebase that is working properly. I know it's a timing issue, just not sure the "correct" way I guess.

Comment: Can you supply a JSFiddle?

Comment: Dit you define `initialize` in **form.js**?

Comment: Sure - I'm not sure how to go about doing that with require though. I mean, beyond copy/paste this into the fiddle, I'm not sure how to actually make it "go".

Comment: @Tim I didn't. I'm not calling an `initialize` method. I just tried it though and get the same error. `form.initialize is not a function`. I updated the js to reflect that.

Comment: What is initialize then in **form.js**? Because you are referencing `initialize` in the return statement. If the variable doesn't exist, a browser might throw an error and abort the script. I'm not sure how *require.js* handles errors, but it might be the source of the problem.

Comment: That was an error on my part, I have updated my initial code snippet to exclude it.

Comment: You might want to upload your code somewhere? I can't really reproduce the error with the current code you supplied.